# How to run lambda function without AWS account and Docker on Local?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to execute Lambda function using SAM-CLI on local without docker.
So, I have question that, is it possible to run lambda function without AWS account and Docker on Local?

Comment: I know that the following article is not exactly what you are looking for. But check it out. There is an example how to do AWS Lambda local run using Python. https://medium.com/geekculture/debug-lambdas-locally-without-sam-docker-or-anythin-eb68761dd9c4

Answer (score 0):

No, docker is a required prerequisite to invoke sam function locally. Even if you use [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), you need docker.